# contextmanager fails with logging

Tags: python, python-2.7, contextmanager

I tried to write a lock functionto have only one instance of my script running at the same time. But contextmanager doesn't like it when I add debug messages or other functions into my code.

Any ideas how to workaround this with the same functionality and log messages?

Lock function:

```
@contextmanager
def lockfile(lock_file='/run/lock/my_script.lock'):
    if os.path.exists(lock_file):
        logging.INFO('Found lock file with pid')
        lf = open(lock_file)
        pid = lf.readline()

        try:
            os.kill(pid, 0)
        except OSError:
            logging.INFO('Removing stale lock file')
            os.remove(lock_file)
        else:
            logging.INFO('Process still running. Aborting')
            sys.exit(1)

    if not os.path.exists(lock_file):
        pid = os.getpid()
        open(lock_file, 'w').write(pid)
        try:
            yield
        finally:
            os.remove(lock_file)
```

call function

```
with lockfile():
    do something
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vagrant/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1733, in <module>
    debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None)
  File "/home/vagrant/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1226, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/vagrant/my_script", line 274, in <module>
    with lockfile():
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
    return self.gen.next()
  File "/vagrant/my_script", line 56, in lockfile
    logging.INFO('Found lock file with pid')
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: `logging.INFO` is a constant ([`20`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging-levels)), you mean [`logging.info`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.info). Python is case sensitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`logging.INFO` is not a function. It's an int object that represent logging level which is not callable.

You may want to use [`logging.info`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.info) instead.

```
...
logging.info('Removing stale lock file')

...
logging.info('Process still running. Aborting')
```